# Подогнать высоту фрейма к минимальной высоте загруженного документа в этот же фрейм

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Доброго времени суток, такая проблема:
Есть ссылки  у всех есть href="" (обычно локальный документ)
Есть один фрейм в который загружается документ указанный в одной из нажатых ссылок как href="" (То есть, жмем  - во фрейме будет так ...src="lol.htm">...).
Иногда внешние документы могут по высоте не вмещаться в этот фрейм, так вот нужно подогнать высоту, что бы норм было.
Пробовал у фрейма onLoad="..." (много вариантов гуглил, ни один не заработал).
Думаю может нужно проверять нажатие на  после чего ждать, что фрейм загрузится и уже выставлять высоту, но в JS я не силен, возможно это и есть моя проблема.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код который берез высоту из окна фрейма

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function iframeLoaded() {
      var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
      if(iFrameID) {
            iFrameID.height = "";
            iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
      }   
  }
</script>
```

iframe

```
<iframe id="idIframe" onload="iframeLoaded()" ...
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52524/discussion-on-answer-by-l-vadim-------).